# Checking if LocalDateTime falls within a time range

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time, localtime, datetime-comparison

I have a time A which should fall within 90 minutes range of timeB (before and after).

Example: if timeB is 4:00 pm , time A should be between 2:30pm (-90) to 5:30pm (+90)

Tried the following :

```
if(timeA.isAfter(timeB.minusMinutes(90)) || timeA.isBefore(timeB.plusMinutes(90))) {
    return isInRange;   
}
```

Can you help me whats wrong with the logic here?

Comment: `||` should be `&&`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [@JB Nizet said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942351/checking-if-localdatetime-falls-within-a-time-range/46943265#comment80832159_46942351), you're using the **OR** operator (`||`).
So you're testing if `A is after B - 90` **OR** `A is before B + 90`. If only one of the conditions is satisfied, it returns `true`.

To check if `A` is in the range, both conditions must be satisfied, so you must use the **AND** operator (`&&`):

```
if (timeA.isAfter(timeB.minusMinutes(90)) && timeA.isBefore(timeB.plusMinutes(90))) {
    return isInRange;   
}
```

---

But the code above doesn't return `true` if `A` is **exactly** 90 minutes before or after `B`. If you want it to return `true` when the difference is also exactly 90 minutes, you must change the condition to check this:

```
// lower and upper limits
LocalDateTime lower = timeB.minusMinutes(90);
LocalDateTime upper = timeB.plusMinutes(90);
// also test if A is exactly 90 minutes before or after B
if ((timeA.isAfter(lower) || timeA.equals(lower)) && (timeA.isBefore(upper) || timeA.equals(upper))) {
    return isInRange;
}
```

---

Another alternative is to use a `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` to get the difference between `A` and `B` in minutes, and check its value:

```
// get the difference in minutes
long diff = Math.abs(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(timeA, timeB));
if (diff <= 90) {
    return isInRange;
}
```

I used `Math.abs` because the difference can be negative if `A` is after `B` (so it's adjusted to be a positive number). Then I check if the difference is less than (or equal) to 90 minutes. You can change it to `if (diff < 90)` if you want to exclude the *"equals to 90 minutes"* case.

---

There's a difference between the approaches.

`ChronoUnit` rounds the difference. e.g. If `A` is 90 minutes and 59 seconds after `B`, the difference will be rounded to 90 minutes and `if (diff <= 90)` will be `true`, while using `isBefore` and `equals` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

LocalDateTime implements the Comparable interface. Why not use it to check if a value falls within a range like this:

```
public static boolean within(
    @NotNull LocalDateTime toCheck, 
    @NotNull LocalDateTime startInterval, 
    @NotNull LocalDateTime endInterval) 
{
    return toCheck.compareTo(startInterval) >= 0 && toCheck.compareTo(endInterval) <= 0;
}
```