# Comparing time in java between epoch milliseconds and LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, time

I have a timestamp in epoch milliseconds and I want to check if it is between two `LocalDateTime` stamps. What's the best way to do this in java?

Comment: Convert the two localDate to milliseconds and compare the longs.

Comment: best in what terms ? time? memory?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: im trying to write a generic function that works for multiple timezones, is there a way to do this comparison without knowing the timezones?

Comment: Something like :

If (localDateTime start <= timeEpochMilliseconds and timeEpochMilliseconds <= LocalDateTime end) {return true }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if LocalDateTime falls within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942351/checking-if-localdatetime-falls-within-a-time-range)

Comment: No, @MeharSawhney, there is no way to do it without knowing the time zone since the answer will be different in different time zones.

Comment: Corner case: when summer time (DST) ends in the fall and clocks are turned back, the same `LocalDateTime` occurs twice. If your epoch time is between the two, the answer to whether it’s between your two times may be unknown. So even when knowing the time zone we cannot give a 100 % sure answer. You decide, of course, if you can live with this uncertainty.

Comment: See also: [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to convert the milliseconds to `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(1);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);

if (date.isAfter(start) && date.isBefore(end)) {
  // date is between start and end
}
```

Comment: This approach assumes the `LocalDateTime` was intended to be in UTC. If it were intended for another time zone, this would yield incorrect results.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

You *cannot* compare a `LocalDateTime` to a moment until assigning a time zone (or offset-from-UTC).

```
org.threeten.extra.Interval                     // Represents a span-of-time attached to the timeline, as a pair of `Instant` objects, a pair of moments in UTC.
.of ( 

    myLocalDateTimeStart
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine a moment by assigning an time zone to a `LocalDateTime` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`, from which we extract an `Instant` to adjust into UTC.
    .toInstant() ,

    myLocalDateTimeStop
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                                // From the `ZonedDateTime`, extract a `Instant` object.

)                                               // Returns `Interval` object.
.contains(        
    Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_463_173_752L )  // Parse a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z as a moment in UTC, a `Instant` object.
)                                               // Returns a boolean.
```

## Details

> Comparing time in java between epoch milliseconds and LocalDateTime

**You cannot.** That comparison is illogical.

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the world.

As such it has no real meaning until you place it in the context of a time zone. If that particular date and time were invalid in that zone, such as during a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cut-over, or during some other such anomaly, the `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDateTime.atZone( z ) ;
```

For comparisons, we will adjust into UTC by extracting an `Instant` object from your start and stop `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
Instant start = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
```

Now parse your count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as a `Instant`. `Instant` has an even finer resolution, nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_463_173_752L ) ;
```

Compare to see if your epoch-milliseconds represent a moment in between our stop and start `Instant` objects. Usually in date-time work, the Half-Open approach is best, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Tip: A shorter way of saying “is equal to or is after” is to say “is not before”.

```
boolean inRange = ( ! instant.isBefore( start ) ) && instant.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

To make this work easier, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. Use the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( start , stop ) ;
boolean inRange = interval.contains( instant ) ;  // Uses Half-Open approach to comparisons.
```

---

**Tip:** If you had intended to be tracking moments, you should not have been using `LocalDateTime` class at all. Instead, use the `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` classes.

[image: table of date-time class in Java, both legacy and modern]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: The **About java.time** sales pitch really doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @shmosel I would think so too, given the context. But often when I omit that section, I get comments asking “What are these classes?”, “Where do I get them?”, “Is this better than Joda-Time?”, “But I use Android before 26?!”   :-/

Comment: Maybe you can link to a wiki somewhere. Also, OP is apparently using java.time already.

Comment: @shmosel It is other readers who make the queries, not the OP. I speak from experience, as I *have* omitted the section on some of my date-time Answers, out of the same concern as yours. And I have rewritten that section numerous times to be as compact as possible.

Comment: @BasilBourque Great answer

Answer (score 1):

When comparing an `Instant` (time-since-Epoch) with a `LocalDateTime`, you always need to consider the timezone of the local times. Here's an example:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();

LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 7, 24, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 7, 24, 23, 59);

final ZoneId myLocalZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");

if (now.isAfter(start.atZone(myLocalZone).toInstant()) 
        && now.isBefore(end.atZone(myLocalZone).toInstant())) {

    // the instant is between the local date-times

}
```